# How to refactor multiple similar Linq queries?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, refactoring

Suppose I have the two following Linq queries I want to refactor:

```
var someValue1 = 0;
var someValue2= 0;
var query1 = db.TableAs.Where( a => a.TableBs.Count() > someValue1 )
                  .Take( 10 );
var query2 = db.TableAs.Where( a => a.TableBs.First().item1 == someValue2)
                  .Take( 10 );
```

Note that only the Where parameter changes. There is any way to put the query inside a method and pass the Where parameter as an argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of couse there is. The where parameter is just a simple closure of type `Func<T, bool>` (where T is the type of your DB items - I don't know them out of your code) and you can wrap it into a (anonymous) function.

```
Func<Func<T, bool>, IEnumerable<T>> MakeQuery = (Func<T, bool> whereParam) => db.TableAs.Where(whereParam).Take(10);
```

Use it like this

```
var query1 = MakeQuery(a => a.TableBS.Count() > someValue1);
```

Comment: Why do you specify the type argument on the rhs? Its inferred from lhs, makes code more shorter and readable.

Answer (score 2):

You can using [`Predicate<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bfcke1bz.aspx).

```
public IQueryable<TableA> Helper(Predicate<TableA> predicate)
{
    return db.TableAs.Where(predicate).Take(10);
}
```

The just call it like that.

```
var query1 = Helper(a => a.TableBs.Count() > someValue1);
var query2 = Helper(a => a.TableBs.First().item1 == someValue2);
```

And give a better namen than `Helper`.

Comment: Kind of off-topic, but shouldn't that method maybe be either private or static or both?

Comment: It depends - it might be a public method of a helper class or a private method of the class that uses it. It might be static, but one might also decide to keep it non-static for better testability. I would not try to guess the best way based on this few lines of code.

Comment: Just a correction, Where accepts Func<T,TResult> and not Predicate<T>, but I got the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the parameter type is a lamba expression `Func<TSource, bool>`

```
Func<Person, bool> c1 = p => p.LastName == "1";
Persons.Where(c1);
Func<Person, bool> c2 = p => p.FirstName == "2";
Persons.Where(c2)
```

Comment: This isn't working: Unsupported overload used for query operator 'Where'.

Comment: Yes, I compiled and ran before posting here.

Comment: All right, I know why. I didn't realize this is for Linq to Sql.

Comment: If you know why please post the answer in the new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/865350/how-to-refactor-multiple-similar-linq-to-sql-queries

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the same way you'd refactor any other code:

```
T MyQuery(U db, Func<TSource, bool> pred) {
  return db.TableAs.Where( pred )
                  .Take( 10 );
}
```

where T and U are whatever types ar erelevant in your query.

Comment: I was not used to lambda expressions, so I didn't realized it was so obvious.

Comment: A lambda expression is nothing more than syntactic sugar for the Func<> delegate with the appropriate generic types inserted. There's no magic. :)

Comment: This solution isn't working: Unsupported overload used for query operator 'Where'.

Comment: Most likely you're using the wrong types then. The first generic parameter for the predicate has to be the element type of the enumerable/queriable it works on. Hard to say exactly what the problem is without seeing some more code (or at least which types we're working with)

Comment: Ah yeah, that's most likely the problem. LinqToSql is a lot more picky because it has to be able to compile the predicate function into SQL.