# How to refactor multiple similar Linq-To-Sql queries?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, refactoring

Suppose I have the two following Linq-To-SQL queries I want to refactor:

```
var someValue1 = 0;
var someValue2= 0;
var query1 = db.TableAs.Where( a => a.TableBs.Count() > someValue1 )
              .Take( 10 );
var query2 = db.TableAs.Where( a => a.TableBs.First().item1 == someValue2)
              .Take( 10 );
```

Note that only the Where parameter changes. There is any way to put the query inside a method and pass the Where parameter as an argument?

All the solutions posted in the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863169/how-to-refactor-multiple-similar-linq-queries) have been tried and failed in runtime when I try to enumerate the result.

The exception thrown was: "Unsupported overload used for query operator 'Where'"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely. You'd write:

```
public IQueryable<A> First10(Expression<Func<A,bool>> predicate)
{
    return db.TableAs.Where(predicate).Take(10);
}
```

(That's assuming that `TableA` is `IQueryable<A>`.)

Call it with:

```
var someValue1 = 0;
var someValue2= 0;
var query1 = First10(a => a.TableBs.Count() > someValue1);
var query2 = First10(a => a.TableBs.First().item1 == someValue2);
```

I *believe* that will work...

The difference between this and the answers to your previous question is basically that this method takes `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` instead of just `Func<T,bool>` so it ends up using `Queryable.Where` instead of `Enumerable.Where`.

Comment: Strangr, I tried both cases:
            Expression<Func<TagFragment, bool>> c1 = t => true;
            Console.WriteLine(db.Table1.Where(c1).Count());

            Func<TagFragment, bool> c2 = t => true;
            Console.WriteLine(db.Table1.Where(c2).Count());
they gave me the same results, no runtime errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want reusability you can try to write your own operators. E.g. instead of repeatedly writing:

```
var query = 
Products
    .Where(p => p.Description.Contains(description))
    .Where(p => p.Discontinued == discontinued);
```

you can write simple methods:

```
public static IEnumerable<Product> ByName(this IEnumerable<Product> products, string description)
{
    return products.Where(p => p.Description.Contains(description));
}


public static IEnumerable<Product> AreDiscontinued(IEnumerable<Product> products, bool isDiscontinued)
{
    return products.Where(p => p.Discontinued == discontinued);
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
var query = Products.ByName("widget").AreDiscontinued(false);
```